# Unable to open more than 1 RDP session at a time

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop

A user has lately been experiencing an issue when trying to connect to 2 different RDP sessions at a time. They will connect to one ok but when trying to connect to another, the session does not appear. They get as far as typing in their credentials clicking connect then nothing happens. As soon as I close the RDP session that is open and working the other session will then pop up.

I can RDP into the users computer and connect to both RDP sessions at the same time fine but when trying to do it locally on their machine it just will not connect.

I have tried connecting on another computer with the same sessions and it works fine. I have also tried reinstalling a fresh copy of windows just in case windows files had become corrupt.

Has anyone come across this issue before or has any idea what it could be? If you need any additional info I will be happy to provide.

Comment: Windows 7 normally only allows one RDP session at a time, if you try to connect two, a popup will come up on the 1st session that allows the first person to allow or block the second connection. The second connection then waits for this response or timeout. Sounds like that's what's happening here.

Comment: Please provide details about the machine(s) you are connecting *to* via RDP.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have since found out what it was. The user was using a card reader which when plugged in would not let more than 1 rdp session( Both sessions are VM's). When I removed the card they were able to connect. Not sure if the card reader is faulty or the sessions are trying to both pull through the reader and only 1 can at a time? Anyway now I know what it is I can get around it.